# How do I aggregate RSS feeds over time from a single source?

Tags: rss, aggregation

I would like to archive specific RSS feeds and grow the database over time. I noticed that older articles drop out of the rss feed and as new ones get added. I want to be able to archive them on my disk so, over a few years, I built an archive. I prefer a linux terminal tool but am okay with GUI.

What tool can I use to do this? I am also okay coding this myself in python if anyone can suggest me some libraries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python feed parser seems to be a good solution.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser

It seems easy to use...

`import feedparser
 d = feedparser.parse('https://www.eff.org/rss/updates.xml')
 for item in d.entries:
    print (item.title)`

`item.id` seems to be unique to check if the feeds are fresh.